# Is the total interval along a path equal to the sum of the intervals along its segments?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, distance

**Context**

While working an exercise I was confronted with the terms *total invariant interval*, and *total interval*.

**Question**

Using mathematics, how are the terms *total invariant interval* and *total interval* related to the term *invariant interval*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the interval can be summed along the worldline.

The reasoning is both mathematical and physical. From a mathematical point of view, one *defines* a path-dependent quantity called total interval using
$$
s = \int_A^B ds
$$
where $A$ and $B$ signify events, the integral is along some path (a worldline) and $ds$ is the interval along each section of the path. Since this is a definition one does not need to prove it. But the reason why it is a *useful* quantity, from a mathematical point of view, is that each $ds$ is Lorentz-invariant, and therefore so is the total, $s$.

Now for the physical reasoning. For each little section of path, we can consider the situation in an inertial frame whose 4-velocity matches that of the worldline in that section. Then $ds$ will have the value of $c dt$ where $dt$ is the time elapsed in that particular frame. But since the laws of physics are independent of inertial frame, the physical system will have its internal evolution consistent with that $dt$. So when we define the total interval the way we are doing, it also corresponds physically to the total internal evolution time that the physical system has on its journey from $A$ to $B$.

In Newtonian physics, that total internal evolution time would be independent of the path (worldline) between $A$ and $B$, for any given $A$, $B$. In relativistic physics it does depend on the worldline. And that corresponds to what is empirically observed.